How to implement this kind of grid
How can I create this component with static data and make it responsive

Here is what I already created:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 columns each taking up equal space */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 rows each taking up equal space */
  gap: 10px; /* Gap between grid items */
  width: 100%; /* Width of the grid container */
  height: 100vh; /* Height of the grid container (100% of the viewport height) */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ccc; /* Background color of grid items */
  border: 1px solid #999; /* Border around grid items */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item">16</div>
</div>



Here is an image preview: 

You could consider doubling the amount of grid layout columns. Then offset every other row by one column, so that it creates the brick-work effect. For the last row, offset the layout further to make the items appear in the middle:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr); /* 4 columns each taking up equal space */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr); /* 4 rows each taking up equal space */
  gap: 10px; /* Gap between grid items */
  width: 100%; /* Width of the grid container */
  height: 100vh; /* Height of the grid container (100% of the viewport height) */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ccc; /* Background color of grid items */
  border: 1px solid #999; /* Border around grid items */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(7n + 5) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.grid-item:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item">16</div>
</div>



For responsiveness, you could consider using CSS rules in media queries to adjust the grid column count and the item offsets to taste.

This is great! Could you also show me a example where the rows have this columns in order. So like 4,5,4,3 as it is in the design's picture
also what would be your solution to responsiveness?

Here is a variation following the design. For responsiveness, you could consider using CSS rules in media queries to adjust the grid column count and the item offsets to taste.
